# send sms to a particular number through Android App programmatically

Tags: android

Actually my concept is with android application code message have to send a particular number. My code is

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
    textPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhoneNo);
    textSMS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);

    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            String phoneNo = textPhoneNo.getText().toString();
            String sms = textSMS.getText().toString();

            try {
                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
                String smsNumber = textPhoneNo.getText().toString();
                  String smsText = textSMS.getText().toString();
                  smsManager.sendTextMessage(smsNumber, null, smsText, null, null);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: add permission of SEND_SMS to your manifest file

Answer (score 1):

Permission required in AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy "Not working" is really annoying answer. Any exception (logcat) or else ?

Comment: no exceptions no errors i got toast message SMS Sent but message not for word to that user.

Comment: Check this example: [Android – Sending SMS from android application](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-sending-sms-from-android-application/)

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy Then how do you know it's not sent?

Comment: i have added that also in  AndroidManifest.xml but it is not working

Comment: sendTextMessage takes two PendingIntent type arguments. You should use them in order to find out if the message has been sent/delivered. Otherwise you have no way of knowing if the message was actually sent.

Comment: @Paresh Mayani my question is we are sending a msg to particular number but from which number it will deliver to a particular number,through code how it will deliver the message